# How to make a Dropdown List shown on top of every parent with position: relative

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve something like shown below.

- The container holds a group of dropdown list that will activate dropdown menu when clicked and the dropdown menu are to be on top of every parent.

[image]

**Faced problem:**

The issue I'm now experiencing is that the dropdown menu hides inside the container rather than appearing on top of the parent level.

**What I've tried:**

I tried position:absolute, and it works well for putting the list on top of each parent.

Dropdown lists in overflow, on the other hand, will keep their position on their set location rather than following their dropdown label.

Thus, the need for position:relative.

---

Could somebody provide some light on this?

Your help is much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/6r94bpof/

```css
    html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .land{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 8fr;
        height: 100vh;
    
    }
    
    .mainmenu{
        border: solid 2px grey;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        display: flex;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .left{
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
    
    .left-selection{
        display: flex;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    
    .right{
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
    
    .right-selection{
        display: flex;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    
    .ddgroup{
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .ddlist{
        position: relative;
        display: none;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .ddlist{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
```

```html
 <html>
    <body>
    <div class="land">
      <div class="mainmenu">
          <div class="left">
              <div class="left-selection">
                  <div class="ddgroup">
                      <ul class="ddmenu">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="ctrl"/>
                          <label class="btn" for="ctrl">Click me!</label> 
                          <ul class="ddlist">
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
                          </ul> 
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="ddmenu">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="ctrl"/>
                          <label class="btn" for="ctrl">Click me!</label>          
                          <ul class="ddlist">
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
                          </ul> 
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="ddmenu">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="ctrl"/>
                          <label class="btn" for="ctrl">Click me!</label>          
                          <ul class="ddlist">
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
                          </ul> 
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="ddmenu">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="ctrl"/>
                          <label class="btn" for="ctrl">Click me!</label>          
                          <ul class="ddlist">
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
                          </ul> 
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="ddmenu">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="ctrl"/>
                          <label class="btn" for="ctrl">Click me!</label>          
                          <ul class="ddlist">
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
                          </ul> 
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="ddmenu">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="ctrl"/>
                          <label class="btn" for="ctrl">Click me!</label>          
                          <ul class="ddlist">
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
                          </ul> 
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="ddmenu">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="ctrl"/>
                          <label class="btn" for="ctrl">Click me!</label>          
                          <ul class="ddlist">
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
                          </ul> 
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="ddmenu">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="ctrl"/>
                          <label class="btn" for="ctrl">Click me!</label>          
                          <ul class="ddlist">
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
                          </ul> 
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="ddmenu">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="ctrl"/>
                          <label class="btn" for="ctrl">Click me!</label>          
                          <ul class="ddlist">
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
                          </ul> 
                      </ul>
                  </div>   
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
              <div class="right-selection">
                <h1>Test<h1/>
                <h1>Test<h1/>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Next time try to make your question clearer , you was very quick in your doubts and ended up not making it very clear . Can I help you if the problem is to create a horizontal menu, but without inputs, its ok for you? (i dont know too much "CSS'ing" inputs XD)

Comment: @EdvaldoFilho noted, with thanks.

sure, as long as the logic on how to solve the issue can be seen :D, I can always change back to inputs

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't copy your html and css so I created my own and did it, if it doesn't matches your query plz tell me I will adjust

```css
 *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}


input{


display:none;
}
ul, li{
    list-style: none;
    
}
ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    gap:1rem;
    padding: 1rem ;
}
li{
    position: relative;
    
}
.dropdown-content {
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: none;
}
.dropdown-content > *{
display: block;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: #38dce5;
margin-top: 0.3rem;
padding: 0.3rem;


}

input:checked ~ .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 

<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="" id="input1">
        <label for="input1">Click me</label>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
     
       <a href="#">Sub 1</a>
       <a href="#">Sub 2</a>
       <a href="#">Sub 3</a>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <input type="checkbox" name="" id="input2">
     <label for="input2">Click me</label>
     <div class="dropdown-content" id="pk">
       <a href="#">Sub 1</a>
       <a href="#">Sub 2</a>
       <a href="#">Sub 3</a>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
         <input type="checkbox" name="" id="input3">
     <label for="input3">Click me</label>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">Sub 1</a>
       <a href="#">Sub 2</a>
       <a href="#">Sub 3</a>
     </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: above solution still having the same effect where its dropdown list is tucked inside the parent.

Comment: @Minorsee can you send me the video or image I can't figure out what exactly you mean by tucked inside parent

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6r94bpof/

you may refer to this fiddle